# How to create groups based on cumulative values

Tags: r

I would like to set groups based on sum of columns

```
ID Value Days
A 0   5
A 1200  20
A 300   40 
A 1000  67    
A 1000  90
A 1000  110
A 500   115
B 0     5
B 500   10
B 600   15 
B 1000  25
B 2000  50
B 900   70
B 1000  90
```

Output

```
ID Group Days
A Doses A 20
A Doses B 90
A Doses C 115
B Doses A 15
B Doses B 50
B Doses C 70
```

I would like to sum values to create groups and retain the corresponding timestamps (days) when they occur.

```
Output (creating 3 groups)
            Values
(Doses A) => 1000 
(Doses B) => 3000 
(Doses C) => 5000
```

Comment: please always share your data as code, not as formatted tables. You can paste the output of `dput(your_data)`. This is also valid for the desired output

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(Value = cumsum(Value),
         Doses = (Value>=1000) + (Value>=3000) + (Value>=5000), .by=ID)%>%
  filter(Value>=1000) %>%
  slice_head(by = c(ID, Doses))%>%
  mutate(Doses = paste('Doses', c('A', 'B', 'C')[Doses])) %>%
  select(ID, Doses, Days)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   ID    Doses    Days
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 A     Doses A    20
#> 2 A     Doses B    90
#> 3 A     Doses C   115
#> 4 B     Doses A    15
#> 5 B     Doses B    50
#> 6 B     Doses C    70
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new=cumsum(Value),
                              new2=case_when(
                                new>=5000 ~ 'C',
                                new>=3000 ~ 'B',
                                new>=1000 ~ 'A'
                              )) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(new2)) %>% 
  group_by(ID,new2) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(new,new2))

# output 

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  ID    Value  Days
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      1200    20
2 A      1000    90
3 A       500   115
4 B       600    15
5 B      2000    50
6 B       900    70
```